# The scanner would not scan the second line

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

I had this code where after reading the first three lines of input, it would just terminate the program and would not let me enter the next line. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class cycle {
public static void main(String[] arg)
{
    System.out.println("Put in numbers");
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    int indicator=Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
    if(indicator==1)
    {
        mission1();
    }
    else if(indicator==2)
    {
        mission2();
    }
    in.close();
}
static void mission1()
{
    Scanner miss1=new Scanner(System.in);
    int citizens=Integer.valueOf(miss1.nextLine());
    String lines=miss1.nextLine();
    lines=lines.replaceAll("\\s", "");
    int length=lines.length();
    String lines2=miss1.nextLine();
    lines2=lines.replaceAll("\\s", "");
    int length2=lines.length();
    while(citizens!=length||citizens!=length2)
    {
        System.out.println("Citizens number do not match, try again" );
        miss1=new Scanner(System.in);
        citizens=Integer.valueOf(miss1.nextLine());
        lines=miss1.nextLine();
        lines=lines.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        length=lines.length();
        lines2=miss1.nextLine();
        lines2=lines.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        length2=lines.length();
        miss1.close();
        if(citizens!=length||citizens!=length2)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Numebr of citizens do not     match. Please enter numbers again");
        }
        else if(citizens==length&&citizens==length2)
        {
            String[] strs=lines.trim().split("\\s");
            length=lines.length();
            int[] dspeed = new int[length];
            for(int i=0; i<length;i++)
            {
                dspeed[i]=Integer.parseInt(strs[i]);
            }   
            String[] strs2=lines2.trim().split("\\s+");
            int[] pspeed = new int[length2];
            for(int i=0; i<length2;i++)
            {
                pspeed[i]=Integer.parseInt(strs2[i]);
            }
            Arrays.sort(dspeed);

            break;
        }
    }


    }
static void mission2()
{

}
}
```

For example, with an input like this:

```
Put in numbers
1
3
1 3 5
1 3 5
```

It would just terminate the program and it is ok, but with an input like this:

```
Put in numbers
1
3
1 3
1 3
Citizens number does not match, try again
1
3
1 3 5
```

The program would terminate before I can't put in the fourth line.

As a test I put in

```
for(int n=0;n<length;n+=1)
{
    System.out.println(dspeed[n]);
}
```

in between Arrays.sort(dspeed[n]) and break, and the result is like this

```
Put in numbers
1
3
1 3
1 3
Citizens number do not match, try again
1
3
1 3 5
3
```

It makes no sense since it is giving me an output of 3 while not letting me enter the second line. So it is like part of the code is being skipped. Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

Edit: For mission1 it suppose to get a number(let's say x), and then get x numbers of different numbers from the next line. Then, it should put those numbers in an array and sort them

Comment: I'm not able to follow what the code does.  What is it supposed to do for mission 1?

Comment: Why are you creating multiple `Scanners`?

Comment: You should rewrite your application to make more sense.Everything is in one method with a cyclomatic complexity around 5 to 6. That is quite a lot of logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of writing my answer I realized what the actual cause of your error is; look at this piece of code:

```
lines=miss1.nextLine();
lines=lines.replaceAll("\\s", "");
length=lines.length();
lines2=miss1.nextLine();
/*Should be lines2!*/
lines2=lines.replaceAll("\\s", "");
/*Should be lines2!*/
length2=lines.length();
```

You're using `lines`for all your variables. Changing `lines` to `lines2` for the `lines2 = ...` and `length2` variables fixed the issue that you posted. I also replaced

```
if (citizens != length || citizens != length2) {
    /*If you decide to keep this, it should not be a "IndexOutOfBoundsException 
    (since no index was out of bounds) but should perhaps be a "IllegalArgumentException" 
    since you supplied it illegal arguments.*/
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Numebr of citizens do not match. Please enter numbers again");
} else if (citizens == length && citizens == length2) { ... }

with

if (citizens == length && citizens == length2) { ... }
```

Since otherwise this would cause the program to crash if you gave it an invalid input twice in a row.

---

### This part of the answer should be considered code-review and is here to (try to) help improve your code structure. Actual answer is above.

This is the entire class code. This seems to have resolved your error and I've also re-structured some of the code and added comments explaining what I edited and why I restructured it. Please leave a comment if anything is unclear or if it didn't actually resolve your error. Please note that the imports are left out of this answer for clarity.

```
public class Cycle {
/* Important! We can re-use the same scanner for all inputs. */
final Scanner in;

public Cycle() {
    in = new Scanner(System.in);
    run();
    in.close();
}

private void run() {
    System.out.println("Input mission number.");
    final int indicator = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
    if (indicator == 1) {
        mission1();
    } else if (indicator == 2) {
        // etc
    }
}

private void mission1() {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Input number of citizens.");
        final int citizens = Integer.valueOf(in.nextLine());

        /* We don't edit these two first inputs just yet since we
         * have to use the un-edited inputs later in our if-else
         * statement. */
        System.out.println("Input first number(s).");
        final String inputOne = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Input second number(s).");
        final String inputTwo = in.nextLine();

        final String lines = inputOne.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        final int length = lines.length();
        final String lines2 = inputTwo.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        final int length2 = lines2.length();

        if (citizens != length || citizens != length2) {
            /* If the number of citizens doesn't match it just
             * continues the while-loop and does it all over
             * again. */
            System.out.println("Citizens number do not match, try again");
        } else {
            /* Here we use the unedited inputs from before - which
             * is why we didn't edit them. */
            final int[] dspeed = createArrayFromInput(inputOne);
            final int[] pspeed = createArrayFromInput(inputTwo);
            break;
        }
    }
}

/* We shouldn't have duplicated code - use a method instead. */
private int[] createArrayFromInput(final String input) {
    final String[] strs = input.trim().split("\\s+");
    /* The arrays should be the same size so use 'strs.length' as
     * length */
    final int[] speed = new int[strs.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
        speed[i] = Integer.parseInt(strs[i]);
    }
    Arrays.sort(speed);
    return speed;
}

public static void main(final String[] arg) {
    /*We should use a class instance instead of static methods and variables.*/
    new Cycle();
}
}
```